# Shell script to parse multiple rows from a single column

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I am working through a really complex and long multi-conditional statement to do this and was wondering if anyone knew of a simpler method. I have a multi-column/multi-row list that I am trying to parse. What I need to do is take the first row which has the "*****" in the 5th position and copy all those entries into the blank spaces on the next few rows and then discard the original top row. What complicates this a bit is that sometimes the next few rows may not have an empty space in all the other fields (see bottom half of original list). If that's the case, I want to take extra entry (Q1 below) and put it at the end of row, in a new column.

Original list:

```
A B C D ***** F G
    E1
    E2
    E3
Q R S T ***** V W
    U1
Q1  U2
```

Final output:

```
A B C D E1 F G
A B C D E2 F G
A B C D E3 F G
Q R S T U1 V W
Q R S T U2 V W Q1
```

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Awk is a good way to do this, show what you've tried and someone should help you fix it.

Comment: @Barmar No I definitely don't want anyone else to write it for me. If someone could just point me in the right direction. Right now I'm using `for i in $myoutput| awk '{print $5}'` to go row by row and check to see if the fifth field is all ********* at which point I start a new row with new field names from $1,2,3,4,6,7.

Comment: You should be doing the whole thing in awk, as in sudo_O's answer.

Comment: could your `E1 E2 E3` rows have more columns, but not from the beginning of line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concise/cryptic one liner:

```
awk '/[*]/{f=$0;p="[*]+";next}{r=$2?$2:$1;sub(p,r,f);p=r;print $2?f" "$1:f}' file
A B C D E1 F G
A B C D E2 F G
A B C D E3 F G
Q R S T U1 V W
Q R S T U2 V W Q1
```

**Explanation:**

```awk
/[*]+/ {                  # If line matches line with pattern to replace
    line = $0             # Store line
    pat="[*]+"            # Store pattern
    next                  # Skip to next line
}
{
    if (NF==2)            # If the current line has 2 fields 
       replace = $2       # We want to replace with the second
    else                  # Else
       replace = $1       # We want to replace with first first

    sub(pat,replace,line) # Do the substitution
    pat=replace           # Next time the pattern to replace will have changed 

    if (NF==2)            # If the current line has 2 fields
       print line,$1      # Print the line with the replacement and the 1st field
    else                  # Else
       print line         # Just print the line with the replacement 
}
```

To run the script save it to a file such as `script.awk` and run `awk -f script.awk file`.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you! But I am still learning awk and may I ask you for some clarification? I understand what `{r=$2?$2:$1;sub(p,r,f);p=r;print $2?f" "$1:f}'` does, but what does the logic do here here: `/[*]/{f=$0;p="[*]+";next}` @sudo_O

Comment: Next question: Where can I send the fruit basket? ;-) Thank you!

Comment: Haha my pleasure :) best way to show thanks it just to upvote.